# Как вывести текст из memo в консоль?

Tags: delphi, консоль

Как вывести текст из memo в консоль?

Пробую так, но не выводится

```
str:=memo1.Lines.Text;
AllocConsole;
try
Write('Grabbing... ');
Readln(str);
writeln('123'+str);
finally
FreeConsole;
end;
```

какие-нибудь идеи есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо выводить текст построчно, т.е сначала получить все строчки из Memo1:

```
...
str:=memo1.Lines.Text;   // получаем текст
for i:=0 to str.count-1 do 
begin
CharToOem(PChar(str.strings[i]), PChar(str.strings[i]));  // для русских букв(модуль
                                                             "windows")
writeln(' '+str.strings[i]);  // вывод в консоль
end;
...
```

Comment: var
    i:integer;
    begin
    ExtractLinks(form5.Edit2.Text, memo1.Lines);
    memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('1.txt');
    str.LoadFromFile('1.txt');
    for i:=0 to str.count-1 do
    begin
    CharToOem(PChar(str.strings[i]), PansiChar(str.strings[i]));
    writeln(' '+str.strings[i]);
    end;
    end;

вот такой код у меня вышел, но сообщение всё равно не выводится, даже консоль не открывается

Comment: Ну консоль открывать вы должны так же, как и в своем примере.